# Check if key exists in another array and get value from it and push to other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these two arrays, I want to check if the titles and keys match and then push the count from typesCount into types.

I have tried to do a map within a map to check the values against each other and produce a new array but it has not worked.

```
const types = [
  {
    title: 'House',
    slug: 'house',
    count: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Car',
    slug: 'car',
    count: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Bike',
    slug 'bike',
    count: 0,
  },
];

const typesCount = [
  {
    key: 'House',
    count: '11',
  },
  {
    key: 'Bike',
    count: '22',
  },
];
```

What I've tried so far

```
const checkForCount = typesCount.map( x => ({
  types.map( y => ({
     title: y.title,
     slug: y.slug,
     count: y.title === x.key : x.count ? y.count,
   }));
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using `map` and `find` like below

```js
const types = [{title:'House',slug:'house',count:0,},{title:'Car',slug:'car',count:0,},{title:'Bike',slug:'bike',count:0,},];

const typesCount = [{key:'House',count:'11',},{key:'Bike',count:'22',},];

//Loop through the actual array 
const res = types.map(type => ({
  ...type,
  //find if the object is present in counts array else use `{}`
  count:(typesCount.find(tCount => tCount.key === type.title) || {}).count || type.count
}))

console.log(res)
```

This can also be done in another way by using `reduce` and `map` like below

```js
const types = [{title:'House',slug:'house',count:0,},{title:'Car',slug:'car',count:0,},{title:'Bike',slug:'bike',count:0,},];

const typesCount = [{key:'House',count:'11',},{key:'Bike',count:'22',},];

//use reduce to format the counts like {House:"11",Bike:"22"}. This will be used while updateing the counts in the actual data
const formattedCounts = typesCount.reduce((res, obj) => {
  res[obj.key] = obj.count;
  return res
}, {})


const result = types.map(type => ({
  ...type,
  //getting the count from formattedCounts object
  count: formattedCounts[type.title] || type.count
}))

console.log(result)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution

```js
const types = [
  {
    title: "House",
    slug: "house",
    count: 0,
  },
  {
    title: "Car",
    slug: "car",
    count: 0,
  },
  {
    title: "Bike",
    slug: "bike",
    count: 0,
  },
];

const typesCount = [
  {
    key: "House",
    count: "11",
  },
  {
    key: "Bike",
    count: "22",
  },
];

const output = types.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  const entry = typesCount.find(({ key }) => key === currentValue.title);

  if (entry) {
    currentValue = { ...currentValue, count: entry.count };
  }

  previousValue = [...previousValue, currentValue];

  return previousValue;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

See

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of keys and counts from your `typesCount`, which looks something like so:

```
{
  House => 11,
  Bike => 22
}
```

You can then use `.map()` on your `types` array, where, for each object, you use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to spread the object properties into a new object literal. You can then update the `count` property to be one from the map you made if it exists, if it doesn't you can default the value to the current count value of the current object.

See example below:

```js
const types = [ { title: 'House', slug: 'house', count: 0, }, { title: 'Car', slug: 'car', count: 0, }, { title: 'Bike', slug: 'bike', count: 0, }, ]; 
const typesCount = [ { key: 'House', count: '11', }, { key: 'Bike', count: '22', }, ];

const counts = new Map(typesCount.map(({key, count}) => [key, count]));
const res = types.map(o => ({...o, count: counts.get(o.title) || o.count}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Elegant solution. A different approach

Comment: Im actually thinking this is better now because get has full support whereas find has no IE11 support.

Comment: @UXCODA If you want IE11 support then all of the current answers won't work due to the spread syntax. You'd need to write your own logic to merge two objects, or use Object.assign() and its [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

Comment: Thanks I suspect our system might have a polyfill but useful just in case. Cheers